# python repeat error

Tags: python, repeat

I am writing a program that reads three lines of input. The first line will be a word, then a number of characters to repeat, then a number of repeats. But unfortunately I am unable to do it can any one guide me by looking at my code. Thanks

```
word = raw_input("Enter the word: ")
length = int(raw_input("Enter the repeat length: "))
count = int(raw_input("Enter the repeat count: "))
print word.repeat() * count
I want this sort of output:
Enter the word: banana
Enter the repeat length: 2
Enter the repeat count: 3
banananana
```

Comment: You should always give an example of the output (or error) you get, and describe how it is different from what you want.  In your example, you don't even use the "length" variable.  What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you're doing something wrong.
I suppose you got the following error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'repeat'`

Since there is no `repeat()` method for `str` in Python.

And I guess you may want this:

```
# gives the first `length` characters in `string` to repeat for `count` times
word[:length] * count
```

**EDITED:**

I see.. Your edit seems to say you want to repeat the **last** `length` of `word`..

Then try `word + word[-length:] * (count - 1)`

Comment: nah @Pengyu CHEN its showing me some sort of syntax error..!!